# What is the error in "install_github" for using an R Package from github

Tags: r, package

I am trying to download and use an R Package provided on github (SvenKlaassen/GGMtest). But I receive an error causing the process to stop. I am using windows.This is the error message:

```
 Error: Failed to install 'GGMtest' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package 
  'C:/Users/MYUSER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeOALa5/file7d43f52565e/GGMtest_0.1.0.tar.gz' had non-zero 
   exit status
```

This seems to be a somewhat common message when searching for the error but I cannot figure out how work this out. The full message is this:

```
install_github("SvenKlaassen/GGMtest")
Downloading GitHub repo SvenKlaassen/GGMtest@HEAD
During startup - Warning message:
Setting LC_CTYPE= failed 
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeOALa5\remotes7d45119371d\SvenKlaassen- 
GGMtest-ddc314d/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'GGMtest':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'GGMtest_0.1.0.tar.gz'

Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE= failed
Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'GGMtest' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) installation of package 
'C:/Users/MYUSER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeOALa5/file7d43f52565e/GGMtest_0.1.0.tar.gz' had non-zero 
 exit status
```

Maybe someone can help!

Comment: It's tough to know as it worked on my computer. Common problems: (1) package dependencies. It asks to update package dependencies for me when I run, so possibly you need to update some dependency. (2) Try using R directly rather than use Rstudio. Idk why but sometimes it fails in Rstudio but works in native R. (3) Could be a versioning problem with your version of R, Rtools or remotes package. You could post in the github support page for this repo and attach relevant versions of your R configuration, packages and OS, see if the author can help with the specific error

Comment: As a workaround, try cloning the repo and then running `devtools::install()` in the cloned directory

Comment: may I ask what you are using? @JonnyPhelps

Comment: `remotes v 2.2.0` & `R 4.0.3` on windows 10

Comment: I have this as well. Remotes package 2.2.0, the latest version of R studio and windows 10...@JonnyPhelps

Comment: How where you able to access the GGMtest package? Just by: install_github("SvenKlaassen/GGMtest") ? maybe I am missing some code?

Comment: @JonnyPhelps could it be what I have described in my last comment or some language/character setting maybe